# Properly Sizing Images (Gallery Slider Section)

Tags: css

I need to have my images appear  properly in a slider.

Here's a code snippet:

```
            <!-- Slide Item -->
            <section class="home-section bg-scroll bg-dark-alfa-50 width='940' height='500' " data-background="images/AJae5W.jpg">
             <div class="js-height-full">
            </section>
            <!-- End Slide Item -->
enter code here
```

Is this a matter I can handle inline? Or must I edit from the actual style sheet?

URL: http://www.ajaesworld.com/1/      #gallery

Answer (score 0):

Try,
 background-position: center 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;

Comment: Like this:
<section class="home-section bg-scroll bg-dark-alfa-50 background-position: center 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; " data-background="images/AJae5W.jpg">